# How can I ignore the property name that I use in the jsonproperty attribute, provided that it is only once

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

My problem is that I deserialize the incoming data and transfer it to this class using jsonproperty. but I don't want to use property name attribute that I use in jsonproperty while serializing.

**example class**

```
public class DocumentDetail
    {
        [JsonProperty("KAREKOD")]
        public string qrCode { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("GTIN")]
        public string gtinNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("LOTNUMBER")]
        public string lotNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**example serialize**

```
{
  DocumentDetail docDetail=new DocumentDetail(){qrCode="123456adsfg789",gtinNumber ="123asdf548654",lotNumber ="1231231sdfg23"};
  var obj=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);
}
```

**example result**

```
{
    "qrCode" : "123456adsfg789",
    "gtinNumber" : "123asdf548654",
    "lotNumber" : "1231231sdfg23"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add a constructor to your class

```
public class DocumentDetail
{
    public string qrCode { get; set; }

    public string gtinNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lotNumber")] // optional, you can assign any name for serialization
    public string lotNumber { get; set; }
    
    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConstructor]
    public  DocumentDetail( string KAREKOD,string GTIN, string LOTNUMBER)
    {
        qrCode=KAREKOD;
        gtinNumber=GTIN;
        lotNumber=LOTNUMBER;
    }
    public DocumentDetail() {}
}
```

and you don't need to include all properties in the constructor, just include the properties that need different names for a serialization and a deserialiazation.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
public class Foo
{
    private string bar;

    public string IncomingBar { set { bar = value; } }
    public string OutgoingBar { get { return bar; } }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 4 month ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.